# How will GUI applications behave if there is no system tray?

Tags: gui, openbox, panel

Currently I'm running Openbox and I have no need for a pane.

However, I know that some applications, like network managers etc, like to place themselves in the system tray - either by default or when minimized.

What would happen if something would try to minimize itself to a nonexistent tray?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: But I am, from my observations the icons just don't appear. But I still don't know what's actually going on and whether there's a specification for these situations etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking a little bit into the [standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-0.2.html) I found this quote

> An application wishing to provide an icon to the system tray should first locate the system tray by requesting the owner window of the manager selection. If the manager selection has no owner, clients may use the method described in the ICCCM (watching for a MANAGER client message) to be notified when a system tray appears.

So the standard says that you don't need to have a system tray, a program should expect the setting of the system tray icon to fail.

A program should then always have a backup behaviour for this case.
But as we all know not all programs are perfect and some programs could end up with no GUI and you need to kill them by hand.